# How to optimize the below query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have one table that table has more than 70 million row. If i execute this query it is taking approximately 1581 secs to complete. How to optimize this query? moreover that table is log table. That table do not have any index. Any suggestion?

```
select a.volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, b.volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg, (a.volumeOfUser_Show_Psg - b.volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg) as totalNumberCancleProgressSaver
from
(select Count(R_CRE_ID) as volumeOfUser_Show_Psg from CADT where CUR_REC like 'Show_Progress_Saver%'
and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate) a,
(select Count(R_CRE_ID) as volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg from CADT where CUR_REC like 'Continue_Progress_Saver%'
and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate) b;
```

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Try to avoid `LIKE` Condition. Trace the query in `Profiler` and open that `.trc` file in `SQL Tuning Advisor` which will guide you how to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I see the following issues:

- You cast 240 million values to date; you can avoid doing this
- You have no indexes on this table you're searching
- You potentially scan it twice when you can do it once

To solve these:

- create a *persisted* computed column whose value is the date casted version of r_cre_id. This means the cast op will happen once upon insert, not every time the query is run..
- INDEX THE COMPUTED COLUMN and the cur_rec column together in the one index. This is the single biggest performance gain you'll achieve, as you'll have an index that covers the entire query
- hit the table/index only once, by doing this kind of pattern:

Query

```
SELECT 
  count(case when cur_rec like 's%' then 1 end) as count_show,
  count(case when cur_rec like 'c%' then 1 end) as count_cont
FROM
  table
WHERE
  computed_column_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate ANd
  (Cur_rec like 'continue_progress_saver%' or cur_rec like 'show_progress_saver%')
```

Do not skip making the computed column. Do not index the date column with the time component (this index will perform better if it is smaller, and that means indexing fewer unique values by reducing the granularity). Make a computed column of the date part only and index it. This query will return results in a few seconds if you do this

Note, if your cur_rec column is highly varied also (I.e. It contains more than a million unique values), you should consider making another computed column of the result of function `LEFT(cur_rec, 20)`, index this computed column instead, and make your query look like:

```
SELECT 
  count(case when computed_column_left20currec like 's%' then 1 end) as count_show,
  count(case when computed_column_left20currec like 'c%' then 1 end) as count_cont
FROM
  table
WHERE
  computed_column_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate AND
  computed_column_left20currec in ('show_progress_saver','continue_progress_s')
```

The reason why I'm recommending making computed columns for these, is because these computed columns have much much fewer unique values. This means that any generated index with have fewer keys. if all we are doing is counting, it is better not to have to count hundreds of millions of index keys that refer to one row each, to get our totals.

See the following for info on creating computed columns:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/

Answer (score 0):

**WITH AS**

```
WITH Data (volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg)
AS 
(
    SELECT Count(1) AS volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, 0 AS volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg
    FROM CADT
    WHERE CUR_REC LIKE 'Show_Progress_Saver%' AND CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate
    UNION
    SELECT Count(1) AS volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, 0 AS volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg
    FROM CADT
    WHERE CUR_REC LIKE 'Continue_Progress_Saver%' AND CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate
)
SELECT SUM(volumeOfUser_Show_Psg), SUM(volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg), (SUM(volumeOfUser_Show_Psg) - SUM(volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg)) as totalNumberCancleProgressSaver
FROM Data
```

**CASE WHEN**:

```
WITH Data (volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg)
AS 
(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CUR_REC LIKE 'Show_Progress_Saver%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, SUM(CASE WHEN CUR_REC LIKE 'Continue_Progress_Saver%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg
    FROM CADT
    WHERE CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate
)
SELECT volumeOfUser_Show_Psg, volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg, (volumeOfUser_Show_Psg - volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg) as totalNumberCancleProgressSaver
FROM Data
```

But anyway, have you created a index for C_CRE_TIME and maybe that combined with CUR_REC ? That casting of Date may be terrible, why is that needed?

Comment: Your query example contains errors and your post contains some typos, please address. It would be better to reduce the granularity of the indexed values for r_cre_time as we only need day precision, not millisecond. An index with e.g.  730 keys covering the last 2 years will work better than an index with 70 million keys, and including extra data in the index will avoid having to hit the table for thousands or millions of rows, just for a count

Comment: may be so, typed as I went. I haven't running them but the idea is to prepare your data and since you are asking of the last days you better index up R_CRE_TIME. Why isn't this Date anyway since you CAST it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below if that gives performance

```
 SELECT volumeofuser_show_psg, volumeofuser_continue_psg, 
     ( volumeofuser_show_psg - volumeofuser_continue_psg ) AS 
           totalNumberCancleProgressSaver 
(
       SELECT 
             COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_rec LIKE 'Show_Progress_Saver%' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "volumeofuser_show_psg",
           COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_rec LIKE 'Continue_Progress_Saver%' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "volumeofuser_continue_psg"

       FROM     cadt 
       WHERE    Cast(r_cre_time AS DATE) >= @fromDate 
                AND Cast(r_cre_time AS DATE) <= @toDate)      
         ) T;
```

Comment: This post doesn't really add anything that lostfields didn't already suggest, by the way. It also doesn't really go far enough to address the inherent infrastructure problems hampering this query performance

Comment: @CaiusJard I posted answer after that it seems someone  has already given  that so

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do the Cartesian join?

ie. `from a,b`

[Here's a nice reference of how this join would work](http://www.sql-ex.com/help/select5.php)

If you didn't perhaps this would provide what you'd like:

```
select  a.volumeOfUser_Show_Psg,
        a.volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg,
        (a.volumeOfUser_Show_Psg - a.volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg) as totalNumberCancleProgressSaver
    from(
            select sum(case when cur_rec like 'Show%' then 1 else 0 end) as volumeOfUser_Show_Psg,
                    sum(case when cur_rec like 'Cont%' then 1 else 0 end) as count_cont as volumeOfUser_Continue_Psg
            from CADT 
            where (CUR_REC like 'Show_Progress_Saver%' or CUR_REC like 'Continue_Progress_Saver%')
                    and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) >= @fromDate and CAST(R_CRE_TIME AS DATE) <= @toDate)
        ) a;
```

Does that provide you with the results you want?

A tip, try to format your code such that statements are on separate lines. This makes for code that's much easier read.

Casting to date for each record will effect performance, it would be better to change @fromDate and @toDate to the same as R_CRE_TIME.
If possible, create an index on the table. This will help immensely.

Without further information on the data, tables involved or intention there's not much else to add.

Comment: Pretty sure that Cartesian product is not an issue, because the subqueries are counts, so they only produce one value and the optimiser will know it has to run the subqueries before it does the join (because it's an aggregate). The fact that it might hit the table twice is an issue, but not necessarily the biggest one thanks to read caching of the data